# Get rid of small silver maples along fence line and around pool area

Tags: lawn-repair, maple, stump-removal

I have a problem with silver maples growing along my fence line, the sides of the house, and around the pool.  Along the house and the pool they are in a 2’ border of river rock.  Along the fence they are in the grass.  They are also popping up behind or underneath other plants (lilacs, I believe).  I do not have a larger tree that is sending roots out.  A lot of these are coming up from “stumps” of previous growths in the same area that I have not managed to remove yet.  Some of these are as big as 6-8” diameter, so I am thinking I need to use some sort of chemical treatment.  Thanks and please let me know if there are any details I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I spent a lot of time looking for solutions, and came up with a few suggestions.  1 - herbicides that are recommended for woody plants (Triclopyr or Picloram as the active ingredient) are the ones that work.  They take a while to work, though.  The chemical should be applied to a freshly cut stump so it absorbs into the root.  This is best done in the fall.  I am going to do it until the damn things are gone.  2 - Dig it out.  These are frequently runners from another tree.  Killing these roots with chemicals may harm the tree.  In my case, there is no tree to worry about.  3 - Be persistent.  It takes a while, and they grow fast and furious.